# Software tool to assist in checking / correcting vBulletin databases

Tags: vbulletin

I have an older version of vBulletin running a forum (3.6.1).  Unfortunately, over the years numerous errors have developed and so the forum is out of sync with it's data, meaning many threads will not show up even though they are confirmed to be still in the database.   Other issues such as broken links to avatars and photos exist as well.  This seems like an indexing issue, however, the vBulletin built in database maintenance and repair routines do not correct the problems.

Is there a known external tool that can check and correct issues with vBulletin forum databases?
If not, what would be the best way to approach a database problem such as this?  Keep in mind there are nearly 100 different tables and nearly as many indicies and nearly 300K posts so it's quite a complex issue.

Failing that, is is possible to hire someone proficient enough to do it?

Comment: Noone knows of any good tools to check forum databases?